# Where can I play poker with a bot?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I developed a poker bot and I would like to make it play live. It seems most platforms do not allow the use of bots. 
Where can I play poker with a bot? 
Do you know of a platform that offers an API to play real money?

Comment: I doubt it as it is probably considered cheating. Definitely not with real money anyway.

Comment: I don't get why it is considered cheating? Because you can read hand histories and human cannot?

Comment: Correct. Computers can also calculate precise probabilities and count cards perfectly. Furthermore, they cannot be "read" since they don't act in a human like manner - they would have the perfect poker face 24/7

Comment: I agree that being able to read a user's history beforehand (even if you have never played with him) is not fair. It can be alleviated by requiring anonymity for each player. If a bot cannot be "exploited", isn't it the job of the player to notice that and move on to another table? If the bot uses any exploitation mechanism, it can be used against him as well.
Anyway, that does not mean there cannot be a poker platform where bot can play against each other :-)

Comment: @MaximeDeBruyn It is true that a human can do anything that a bot can, but humans make mistakes much more frequently than a bot would. If a bot uses an exploitation mechanism, it does not necessarily mean that that same mechanism can be used against the bot. Exploiting other players and being "exploitable" are two different things. When players play online poker, they are making the assumption that they are playing exploitable players (i.e. humans). If they let one bot play, what is stopping all the other botters from playing as well, making it impossible to be a profitable player online?

Comment: @MaximeDeBruyn "isn't it the job of the player to notice that and move on to another table?" the thing is, most people don't want to play vs. bots because bots have an enormous advantage. That's why the sites don't allow them, they'd lose their primary customers. It would be interesting to see a site that allows bots if the player would be tagged as a bot, meaning that players would know what they're up against and therefor be able to choose whether to play or not. But using a bot, pretending to be a normal person, is simple fraud.

Comment: If you are interested in a poker platform for bots, check https://pkr42.com

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with play money. You may want to ask poker sites if you would be allowed to test your bot there. Some sites may even find it interesting as they can use it as a way to test their anti-cheaters security procedures.

Playing for real money is a different story, though. Every site I can think of explicitely bans bots from their site, while restricting the use of auxiliary software to a very limited list of programs to choose from (with a human player actually making the decisions, of course) It you are caught using illegal software, your fund will be frozen and the site will try to take legal actions against you

In countries that regulate online poker, you may get in big trouble. Some contemplate fines or even prison time for online poker/gambling scammers. By the way, I would be pleased to destroy your bot in any game you want

Comment: I like your spirit.

Comment: @MaximeDeBruyn No, seriously, where can I go to beat the s*** out of it?

Comment: Nowhere at the moment. I would very much appreciate a place where bots and humans can compete, but it does not exist at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test your bot have it play pokersnowie for instance.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting.